# How std::conditional works

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

We have this little metaprogramming marvel called `std::conditional` described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). In the same reference it says that a possible implementation is

```
template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

So if in code I do something like

```
typename std::conditional<true,int,double>::type a;
```

the compiler will follow the first definition and if I do something like

```
typename std::conditional<false,int,double>::type b
```

the compiler will take the second. Why does that work ? What compilation rule is in place here ?

Comment: The rule in place is partial template specialization.

Answer (score 16):

In short it has to do with template specialization rules. These are like function overloads but for types.

Here compiler prefers a more specialized type to the more general type.

```
template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

So if a template instantiation `conditional<false, ...>` is seen by compiler it finds:

- the general template `template<bool B, class T, class F> struct conditional`
- all its specializations: `template<class T, class F> struct conditional<false, T, F>`

At that point it tries to match as many specialized arguments as possible and ends up selecting the specialization with `false`.

For example introducing another version like:

```
template<class F>
struct conditional<false, int, F> { typedef int type; };
```

and instantiating a template type like `conditional<false, int, double>` will prefer specialization

`template<class F> struct conditional<false, int, F>`

to

`template<class T, class F> struct conditional<false, T, F>` which is more general compared to the version with 2 specialized paramaters.

#### Some tricks at this point:

It is even OK to just declare the most generic case (i.e. generic form of the template is just declared but not defined) and only have specializations for cases you really intend to have. All non-specialized cases will result in compile errors and asking the user to specialize the case for a particular type.

Comment: Oh, nice. Thank you very much. This meta-programming  tricks are so smart and at the  same time looks like hacking. I wonder if this type_traits one day will be first citizens in C++ and be implemented directly by the compiler in a kind of simpler template conditional  language.  Although it might be a real challenge for the compiler developers.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does that work ? What compilation rule is in place here ?

I'm not an expert but I'll try to explain from the pratical point of view.

Hoping to use the rights terms...

With

```
template <bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };
```

(but, with C++11, I prefer

```
template <bool B, typename T, typename>
struct conditional { using type = T; };
```

) you declare the template

```
template <bool, typename, typename>
struct conditional;
```

and define the generic (not specialized) version.

With

```
template< class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

(or, in C++11,

```
template <typename T, typename F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { using type = F; };
```

) you define a partial specialization of `conditional`

When the template arguments of a class (or struct) match two or more definitions, the compliler choose the more specialized one; so, for

```
typename std::conditional<false,int,double>::type
```

both definitions of the class match so the compiler choose the specialized one (the specialized with `false`) anche `type` is `double`.

For

```
typename std::conditional<true,int,double>::type a;
```

only the generic version match, so `type` is `int`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that the second declaration were actually seen as an specialization. The more specialized, the more precedence it has. Amazing stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In most of the template meta programming main rule at play here is SFINAE(Substitution failure is not an error). According to this rule if compiler not find the type then instead of throwing an error it moves forward and check if there is any future statement that can provide type information.