# How can I get the integral type of a template argument regardless of whether it's an enum or not

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I'm getting the error:

```
Error   C2154   '_Ty': only enumeration type is allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__underlying_type'
```

I thought it shouldn't be resolving underlying_type to underlying_type, because I first check whether T is an enum. Here is the code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static inline constexpr bool isArgIntegral = std::is_integral<T>::value;
    static inline constexpr bool isArgEnum = std::is_enum_v<T>;

    using integral_underlying_type = std::conditional<isArgEnum, std::underlying_type_t<T>, T>;



};



int main()

    Foo<int> g; // only enumeration type is allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__underlying_type' 
}
```

So is it the case that in a call to std::conditional, instead of first checking the condition (1st argument), it creates the classes of the 2nd and 3rd arguments regardless of the condition, and hence why I'm getting the error that I can't call underlying_type with an 'int'?

How do I go about getting the integral type of the T template argument, whether it's an integral or an enum?

Edit: My next attempt is to place the typedef in an if constexpr:

```
if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>)
{
    using integral_underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
// Now std::underlying_type_t won't be called at all unless T is enum, right?
}
```

Comment: `std::conditional` is a template – and templates provide a separate type for any instantiation. But to be able to determine the instantiation's type, all arguments need to be evaluated...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Might be of interest (though don't think it's a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550976/how-stdconditional-works

Comment: On paper you could work around it if you don't use  the `underlyong_type_t` utility (since it forces instantiation). Just delay it one step `typename conditional_t<isArgEnum, underlying_type<T>, type_identity<T>>::type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`std::integral_underlying_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) is not SFINAE friendly until C++20.

You can then delay instantiation of `std::underlying_type<T>::type`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using integral_underlying_type =
        typename std::conditional_t<std::is_enum_v<T>,
                                    std::underlying_type<T>,
                                    type_identity<T>>::type;
};
```

Notice the double `::type` in `std::conditional<cond, T1, T2>::type::type` (hidden with `_t`). The extra `::type` is done outside the conditional instead of inside (and so the need of `type_identity`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The problem is that whether the condition `isArgEnum` is `true` or `false` (i.e. whether `T` is enum or not), `std::underlying_type_t<T>` has to be specified as the template argument for `std::conditional`.

You can apply partial specialization like

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct Foo
{};
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>>
{
    using integral_underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
};
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
{
    using integral_underlying_type = T;
};
```

Comment: When you write std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>> as the second template argument in the specialisation, because you didn't provide the second argument to std::enable_if_t I don't understand what the typedef is, because it's T = void. Then that looks like you wrote "std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, void>" I don't get that.

Comment: @Zebrafish `std::enable_if<std::is_enum_v<T>>::type` is void if `T` is an enum. If it's not then it's a substitution failure. But since it's in the immidiate context it's not an error. SFINAE. So when the type does resolve to `void` it will match the base template, which makes the specialization valid.